# Run page shortcut in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a shortcut, for example `CMD+0` (on macOS) and i would like to run it on the browser every x minutes, maybe using a script in the browser console like this:

```
function performMyShortcut(){
    // perform shortcut
    console.log("shortcut performed"); 
} setInterval(performMyShortcut,60000)
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically) answer your query?

Comment: @VedantBang, unfortunately no, I would need a script to be inserted in the google console that performs the combination of buttons every 10 minutes for example

Comment: If you don't want to simulate key press events programmatically, it isn't clear then what "run shortcut" means.

Comment: If you notice between the answers it is not possible to do it apparently, because **programmatic keyboard events will have led to spoofing attacks.** so I think I will do it via python

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by writing a simple python script that performs the combination of keys every x seconds, however the script must be run locally,

```
import threading
import keyboard

shortcut = 'Command+0'

def performShortcut():
  threading.Timer(200.0, performShortcut).start()
  keyboard.press_and_release(shortcut)

performShortcut()
```